# Expected size of the smallest preimage set

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let $f$ a function from $\{0, 1 \}^{2n}$ to $\{0, 1 \}^{n}$ uniformly picked at random. I would like to have an estimation of the expected size of the smallest premiage set of $f$, more formally $\mathbb{E}_{f \leftarrow \left(2^n\right)^{2^{2n}}} \left(\min \left(|f^{<-1>}\left( i\right) |\right)_{i \in \{ 0,1\}^{n}} \right)$.

Intuitively I think this set is very small (in $O\left(n\right)$), but I can't prove anything so tight.

Comment: I doubt the preimage is that small. With relabeling, your random function is from $X^2$ to $X$, so I would expect most if not all preimage sets close to the size of $X$. To strengthen this intuition, pick a small subset $Y$ of $X^2$. Off of $Y$, the number of functions on the complement with less than full image is so much smaller than those with full image.  Gerhard "Multinomial Distribution Has Small Tails" Paseman, 2019.01.07.

Comment: I'm agree that most of the set will be of same size of $X$. But it's not obvious (and chebychev inequality don't give any intuition on that result) that there is no set with small cardinality, and I don't understand the reasoning with $Y$...

Comment: The reasoning with Y is that if the expected set size is small, then (by looking at all subsets of that size), there should be a lot of functions on the complement of Y with less than full image.  I maintain there aren't enough if the size of Y is logarithmic with respect to the size of the whole space. Try a sum over all small subsets Y of all functions whose image off of Y is not full. Even with overcounting, the number should be exponentially small with respect to all functions when Y is quite small.  Gerhard "A Big Use Of Smallness" Paseman, 2019.01.07.

Comment: I don't have time now for a long answer. You are considering the order statistics of the multinomial distribution. A precise answer to your question (in form of a limit theorem for the occupation of the smallest cell occupancy) is given in the book [1] (theorem 7 on p.112 (essentially confirming Gerhard Paseman's intuition)).

[1]  Kolchin,V.F. and Sevast'yanov,B.A. and Chistyakov, V.P.,  Random
  Allocations. V.H. WINSTON & SONS, Washington, D.C., 1978.

Comment: I would use the following heuristic: as mentioned you are taking a random function from $M^2$ points to $M$ points. The number of times that the value $i$ is taken is close to normal with mean and variance both equal to $M$. These random variables are close to independent. So we'll approximate by $Z_i\sim \mathcal N(M,M)$, or $Z=M+(\sqrt M)N$ where $N$ is a standard normal and $Z_i$ is the number of times the value $i$ is taken. Now since there are $M^2$ random variables, you solve $\mathbb P(Z<L)=1/M^2$ for a good approximation of the typical smallest bin size.

Comment: This gives (I think) $L=M-2\sqrt{\log M}$ as a fairly good approximation to the smallest bin size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer but easy to obtain. See the  reference by @esg in the comments for the full answer.

I will give a very loose upperbound to this probability, which still tends to zero quite fast with increasing $N.$ You have $N^2$ balls thrown into $N$ bins where $N=2^n.$ So the probability that the lightest loaded bin has less than $N^\theta$ balls can be upper bounded (using the union bound in the first step)
$$
\mathbb{P}[Min<N^\theta]\leq 
N \sum_{0\leq k < N^\theta} \mathbb{P}[X_1=k]=
N \sum_{0\leq k < N^\theta} \binom{N^2}{k} 2^{-N^2}
$$
where $X_1$ is the number of balls in the first bin. The binomial coefficients

$$\binom{N^2}{k}$$ are superincreasing in $k$ so upperbounding by the largest coefficient gives

$$
\mathbb{P}[Min<N^\theta]\leq N^{1+\theta} \binom{N^2}{N^\theta} 2^{-N^2}\sim
 N^{1+\theta} 2^{-N^2(1-\mathbb{H}(N^{\theta-2}))}.
$$
by the [entropy approximation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236508/are-there-good-bounds-on-binomial-coefficients/236511#236511) to the binomial coefficient.
Using the crude bound $\mathbb{H}(p)< 2\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ we still get a bound that goes to zero exponentially fast.

Comment: I'm agree with every part of the reasoning except the last step with the crude bound. I don't understand how we could use it. Shouldn't we upper bound entropy instead lower bound it?

Comment: Thanks, you're right of course.

Comment: Okay I'm conviced. Thanks a lot!