# A combinatorial question about encoding the subsets of logarithmic-bounded cardinality

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, combinatorial-optimization

Let $k \in \mathbb N - \{0\}$ and  $f(n) = \binom n 0 + \binom n 1 + \dotsc + \binom n {\log^k n}$.

Our question is:

$f(n) = o(2^{\log^{k+1} \ (n)})$ or $f(n) = \Theta(2^{\log^{k+1} \ (n)})$, which one exactly holds?

(where $\log(n) = \lceil \log_2(n) \rceil$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.)

$\ $

This question arose when we intended to encode some sets as strings surjectively

Denote $[n] = \{0, 1, 2,\dotsc n-1\}$ and let $g(n) = \Theta(2^{\log^{k+1} \ (n)})$ be a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.

We wonder whether there is a *surjection* from $\{S \mid S\subseteq [n] \text{ and } |S|\leq \log^k(n)\}$ to $\{0,1\}^{\leq g(n)}$, where $\{0,1\}^{\leq g(n)}$ is the set of binary strings of length no larger than $g(n)$

If $f(n) = o(2^{\log^{k+1} \ (n)})$, no such surjection exists.

If $f(n) = \Theta(2^{\log^{k+1} \ (n)})$, we may choose a precise $g(n)$ to make the surjection possible.

Comment: Asymptotic of such sums is well-studied. E.g., check answers at https://mathoverflow.net/q/55585

Comment: also related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236508/are-there-good-bounds-on-binomial-coefficients/236511#236511

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Big-Theta, not big-Oh.